# Travelling to UK and Ireland

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, ireland

I am an Indian studying in Austria. I have a Studyweek program in Enniscrone, North West Coast of Ireland. I want to know whether I can visit UK with that Visa.

Comment: Does the visa say BIVS on it?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I hope BIVS is British-Irish Visa. I have not still applied. I want to know the details to apply. If it is BIVS can I go to UK? Is there another Visa that which is not BIVS?

Comment: As far as I understand it, you'll automatically get the BIVS endorsement if you qualify for it (i.e., if you are not banned from the UK or something unusual like that).  But I don't know much about the BIVS scheme, so I could be wrong about that.  Perhaps someone with first-hand experience will be able to add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The British Irish Visa Scheme allow for travel to and around the Common Travel Area (CTA) on a single visa. A non-BIVS visit visa issued by Ireland will not allow you to visit the UK from Ireland http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/check-irish-visa